# C++ code for finding a substring, logical error

Tags: c++

Hey guys i have made a function that is supposed to find a sub string from the main string but it is not working, here is the code:

```
char *mystrstr (char *s1, char *s2) 
{
    int i=0, j=0, k=0,t=0, l;
    char* s3 = NULL;
    char* s4 = NULL;
    l = mystrlen (s2);
    k = mystrlen(s1);

    //s1 is the main string and s2 is the substring
    if (*(s1 + i) == '\0') //checks if the main string is not null.
        return s1;



    while (*(s1 + i) != '\0' && *(s2 + i) != '\0')// if both the strings are not null then the program proceeds

        {
            while (s1[i] != s2[0] && s1 != NULL)//loop runs till the first letter of substring is found in the main string.
            {
                i++;
            }

            if (*(s1 + i) == '\0')
                return NULL;

            t = i;//stores the position where the first substrign was found
            while (s1[i] == s2[j] && s1[i] != '\0' && s2[j] != '\0')
            {
                i++;//takes tho the nextl letter of the main string
                j++;//to the next letter of the substring.
            }
        }
    if (l == j)//if all letters of the substring is found in the main string only then this condition will be true.
    {
        s3 = &s1[t];
    }
    return s3;
}
```

can anyone tell what is wrong, or atleast give me a hint?

So according to the suggestions given I have changed my code and it gives me the desired result. Here is the new code-

char *mystrstr(char *s1, char *s2)
 {

```
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, t = 0, l;
char* s3 = NULL;
char* s4 = NULL;
l = strlen(s2);
k = strlen(s1);

if (*(s1 + i) == '\0' && *(s2 + i) != '\0')
    return NULL;

if (*(s1 + i) != '\0' && *(s2 + i) == '\0')
    return s1;

if (*(s1 + i) == '\0')
    return s1;


while (*(s1 + i) != '\0')
{
    while (s1[i] != s2[j] && s1 != NULL)
    {
        i++;
        j = 0;
    }
    if (*(s1 + i) == '\0')return NULL;
    t = i;
    while (s1[i] == s2[j] && s1[i] != '\0'&&s2[j] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    if (l == j){
        s3 = &s1[t];
        return s3;
    }
}
return NULL;
```

}

Is there anyway to make to make the code more efficient. I am using this code to find a sub-string form the main-string.

Comment: sorry for poor english

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger.

Comment: Why don't use `substr` from class `std::string` ?

Comment: this is just a part of a long code so how do use a debugger through just this specific segment. (I am new to coding) @RichardCritten

Comment: Can you tell me how is it not working? Do you get an exception? Is it logically wrong? Can you shed some light on the output? Maybe there is a pattern.

Comment: When I run the program the cursor just blinks but no result is displayed but it complies perfectly. SO I guess there is some logical error.

Comment: @Caduchon classes are not allowed, functions and pointers are allowed and I cannot us any library file

Comment: What do you output? Here you have a function, which returns something. You expect to see something on the console. Maybe the output is not printed?

Comment: @LajosArpad s3 is supposed to store the address of the first character of main-string that matches the substring and return that.

Comment: Yes, as we can see from the code. But where do you print the result to the console? You state that this is "not working" because you do not see something on the console. This is either a problem in the function, a problem in calling the function or a problem in displaying the result. I was asking for details about how do you display the result. It is possible that your function works well, but you just do not see the result due to a lack of displaying it.

Comment: @LajosArpad The function call is correct. The problem I guess is in displaying the result. When I use "llama" as the main string and "am" as the sub string, t is supposed to store 2 but it stores 4. I found this out using debugger (which I am still learning to use) and s3 is storing Null which means the code is not existing the first while loop.

Comment: Trying to understand your code, I get the feeling that it'd have to be changed in much more than just one place to produce the desired result. Can you describe your algorithm in prose or in high-level pseudo-code? Maybe the flaw isn't so much in the implementation as in the concepts used.

Comment: @das-g I get the same feeling. I do not understand how do you want me to expalin the code?

Comment: Not the code. The algorithm (the recipe describing how the return value shall be computed, independent of the used programming language). Imagine the characters are on magnets on your fridge, in one line for `s1` and in another for `s2`. Now tell a me (a human) what to do with those two lines of magnets to get the desired result.

Comment: @das-g well I am trying to compare every string of s1 with the string of s2. As soon as i find the first character of s2 in s1 i return the position of that character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in this line:

```
while (*(s1 + i) != '\0' && *(s2 + i) != '\0')
```

This will not exist unless there is a `'\0'` in the very same position of the strings. You should use an `||` and also, you should think about the indexing as well. Maybe you want to use `j` for the indexing of `s2`.

```
if (*(s1 + i) == '\0')
                return NULL;
```

The code above returns `NULL` when you reach the end of `s1`. What happens if `s2` is exactly at the end of `s1`? It will return `NULL`. So this is another bug, as it is assuming that if you reach the end of the string, then the substring was not found.

You should also check how `i` and `j` progresses. If it does not exit from the `while` loop, then it never reaches the `return`. If you debug with "run to cursor" to your `return` statement, is the debugger jumping there? If the program is not running forever, then it will eventually stop, so it will not run your `while` forever. You should check all these.

I am just giving you some ideas how to solve the problem, I do not want to solve your homework.

Comment: thanks for helping me i tried changing the code but it is not working.  if I enter main string as "llamq" and sub string as"am", t should be at 2 but itis at 4. So I think i need to make more changes but thank u.

Comment: Yes, you need to change a few things. But never tell us something is not working. Always describe the exact behavior you experience.

Comment: hey i did improve my code and it also gives me the required results. If it is not a problem to you, can you please judge my code and tell me how sloppy or good it is, or is there any better way to do it. you do not need to write exactly how can I improve my code, just tell me how sloppy it is. Thak you ver much for you help.

Comment: I have been looking at your code. It is certainly much better than the earlier version. Before the while, i is 0, therefore you can simplify your conditions. Note, that if you keep them as simple as possible, then it will be easier to improve it later when it is no longer fresh in your mind. You need to slightly improve the structure of your code, but you are on the right track. All in all, the code can be improved, but it is already much better than the previous version, so you are improving.